# Are there any bricks to make big size robots?

Tags: robotic

I found a robot called `meccanoid 2XL` but it's humanoid robot and I think it's hard to control it. I am looking for a robot like the pic, that stands on wheels instead of legs, and has about 150CM height. 
[image]

Are there any bricks for such robot? Or maybe bricks in smaller size that I can build it exactly in larger size(I mean model it in solidworks and then 3d print it in larger size)?

Comment: You can build up Lego bricks to create large structures (much larger than that, certainly), but they are fairly heavy, so you might have issues motorising it sufficiently to move. An alternative would be to build a low level motorised frame, with a lightweight decorative cowl made from some other material connecting to other functional parts. If you're doing that, though, the use of Lego might not be the best choice for the base

Comment: The question about how to build and control a large humanoid robot is too broad. What have you tried so far, what specific problems do you have? Are you sure you are asking about LEGO?

Comment: @Aziraphale: I didn't know here we must ask question specifically about LEGO! I thought all the bricks or such things could be considered here!

BTW, if I want to ask better question, I need to build a cheap prototype, and this is my first experience. I don't know how to build it's skeleton and how to cover it by what material?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What works and what doesn't? What exactly do you want to model in solidworks?